# Installing spacy returns 'set_default_tensor_type' error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, pytorch, spacy

In a Jupyter Notebook, using Python 3.9.9

I went to https://spacy.io/usage and followed the instructions for installing Spacy

• MacOS/OSX

• conda

• virtual env

• English

• efficiency

```py
!python -m venv .env
```

my virtual environment's name is firstEnv

```py
!source .env/bin/activate
```

```py
!conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

```py
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I then import spacy

```py
import spacy
```

spacy version is 3.2.0

Instantiate the class

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Returns error

````py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/dp/5k1wgpbj6d72lnbdgvwv16l40000gn/T/ipykernel_41554/3909579629.py in <module>
----> 1 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in load(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
     49     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     50     """
---> 51     return util.load_model(
     52         name, vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config
     53     )

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    418             return get_lang_class(name.replace("blank:", ""))()
    419         if is_package(name):  # installed as package
--> 420             return load_model_from_package(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    421         if Path(name).exists():  # path to model data directory
    422             return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model_from_package(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    451     """
    452     cls = importlib.import_module(name)
--> 453     return cls.load(vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    454 
    455 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/__init__.py in load(**overrides)
      8 
      9 def load(**overrides):
---> 10     return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model_from_init_py(init_file, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    613     if not model_path.exists():
    614         raise IOError(Errors.E052.format(path=data_path))
--> 615     return load_model_from_path(
    616         data_path,
    617         vocab=vocab,

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model_from_path(model_path, meta, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    486     overrides = dict_to_dot(config)
    487     config = load_config(config_path, overrides=overrides)
--> 488     nlp = load_model_from_config(config, vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude)
    489     return nlp.from_disk(model_path, exclude=exclude, overrides=overrides)
    490 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model_from_config(config, vocab, disable, exclude, auto_fill, validate)
    523     # registry, including custom subclasses provided via entry points
    524     lang_cls = get_lang_class(nlp_config["lang"])
--> 525     nlp = lang_cls.from_config(
    526         config,
    527         vocab=vocab,

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/language.py in from_config(cls, config, vocab, disable, exclude, meta, auto_fill, validate)
   1753         # then we would load them twice at runtime: once when we make from config,
   1754         # and then again when we load from disk.
-> 1755         nlp = lang_cls(vocab=vocab, create_tokenizer=create_tokenizer, meta=meta)
   1756         if after_creation is not None:
   1757             nlp = after_creation(nlp)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/language.py in __init__(self, vocab, max_length, meta, create_tokenizer, batch_size, **kwargs)
    174         if vocab is True:
    175             vectors_name = meta.get("vectors", {}).get("name")
--> 176             vocab = create_vocab(self.lang, self.Defaults, vectors_name=vectors_name)
    177         else:
    178             if (self.lang and vocab.lang) and (self.lang != vocab.lang):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/vocab.pyx in spacy.vocab.create_vocab()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/vocab.pyx in spacy.vocab.Vocab.__init__()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/vectors.pyx in spacy.vectors.Vectors.__init__()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/backends/__init__.py in get_current_ops()
    124     """Get the current backend object."""
    125     if context_ops.get() is None:
--> 126         require_cpu()
    127     return cast(Ops, context_ops.get())
    128 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/util.py in require_cpu()
    164 
    165     ops = get_ops("cpu")
--> 166     set_current_ops(ops)
    167     set_torch_tensor_type_for_ops(ops)
    168 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/backends/__init__.py in set_current_ops(ops)
    132     context_ops.set(ops)
    133     _get_thread_state().ops = ops
--> 134     set_torch_tensor_type_for_ops(ops)
    135 
    136 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/firstEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/util.py in set_torch_tensor_type_for_ops(ops)
    487             torch.set_default_tensor_type("torch.cuda.FloatTensor")
    488         else:
--> 489             torch.set_default_tensor_type("torch.FloatTensor")
    490     except ImportError:
    491         pass

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'set_default_tensor_type'

​```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had to updated pytorch

in your terminal, type:

```
$! pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
```